# No puedo iniciar actividad dentro de un método

Tags: java, android-studio, método

Tengo el siguiente código

```
public static void enviarCorreuMetode(final String correuClientString, final String missatgeClientString, Button btn_enviarCorreu){


btn_enviarCorreu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String[] TO = {"dasdsad@gasdas.com"}; //Direccions email a enviar.
        String[] CC = {""}; //Direccions d'email amb copia

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(correuClientString));
        emailIntent.setType("SI NO VA BE AIXO ES UNA PROVA");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "REQUEST");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,missatgeClientString); // * configurar email aquí!


        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email."));

    }
    });
}
```

Es un método para enviar un correo pero me da error a la última línea, donde intento iniciar la actividad.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email."));
```

Este código lo tengo en una clase.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: No da error especifico pero es como si no pudiera hacer un start de un intento en una clase a parte o en un metodo.

Comment: Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4883199/5587982), probando a poner `emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");` si no funciona, revisa las diversas soluciones que se aportan allí comparando con tu código. Y, no entiendo por qué dices que *da error en esta línea* y luego cuano @SJuan76 te pregunta por el error dices que no da error específico ¿?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki, mira el logcat cuando se ejucuta el metodo y dimos que imprime.

Comment: Al final tuve que añadir el código en el main, se ve que no puedo iniciar una actividad fuera en una clase. Gracias por la ayuda.